# collection inside a collection in json store ibm worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Is it possible to define or declare a collection inside another collection in json store IBM worklight. like- Objects will have sub objects. Let me know the API or whatever syntax needs to be followed.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not. You could just simply stringify the JSONStore collection object and store it as a record in another collection, but if you are talking about joining two different collection using a common index you can do that using additional search fields. I created a blog just for this. [Blog Post](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/02/24/working-jsonstore-collections-join/)